# python sets with integers is splitting integers greater than 10 into two digits

Tags: python, set

I'm trying to initialize a list of sets in python.  Each set initially contains a single integer representing a numbered vertex in a graph.

```
for x in graph:
    setList.append(set(x))
print setList
```

If the graph has 10 vertices it will print out the following:

```
[set(['0']), set(['1']), set(['2']), set(['3']), set(['4']), set(['5']), set(['6']), set(['7']), set(['8']), set(['9']), set(['1', '0'])]
```

Why is 10 getting split into 1, 0 ?

```
set(['1', '0'])
```

Comment: `x` is a string.  `set(<iterable>)` consumes the iterable, and strings iterate over their characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are strings, not integers, and strings are sequences. That means calling `set()` on them creates a set of each element in the sequence - which in the case of strings are the individual characters. This ought to fix your problem:

```
for x in graph:
    setList.append(set([x]))
print setList
```

Or if you want integers instead:

```
for x in graph:
    setList.append(set([int(x)]))
print setList
```

These work because now that `x` has been wrapped in a list, Python iterates over that list to populate the set, rather than attempting to iterate over `x` itself (which would have raised a `TypeError` if `x` had actually been an integer, because integers aren't iterable).

Comment: ++, and you probably to run `int(x)` at some point like the second sample (but maybe earlier, when you first get the values rather than when you make the set). If you're already thinking of the inputs as integers, you should make them `int`s to avoid other surprises later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
setList.append({x})
```

example:

```
>>> set('10')
{'1', '0'}
>>> a={'10'}
>>> a
{'10'}
```